# Trying to print previous line in awk, but instead appears to print current line twice

Tags: awk

I'm trying to use awk to imitate `uniq -d` on specific fields to print the line currently being read as well as the previous line using the first solution from [here](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/233487-any-solution-get-previous-line-awk.html), but it appears to print the same line twice.

Here's a sample of the stuff in the file.

```
130 chr1    7237    7238    0k9imgkt
135 chr1    7637    7637    b9gko
138 chr1    7908    7908    kob9g
139 chr1    8045    8045    34e5rg  4r
151 chr1    8329    8329    b
151 chr1    8346    8346    345y46htyh
151 chr1    8346    8346    76jtuj
152 chr1    8358    8358    asfge
```

Here's the line I used. I'm trying to compare rows based on the second, third, and fourth fields; if two or more rows are identical in those fields, print the entirety of those rows. Also, it's safe to assume that the rows are sorted based on fields 1, 2, and 3.

```
awk '{prev = $0; ++array[$2$3$4]; if(array[$2$3$4] == 2) {print; curr = $0; $0 = prev; print; $0 = curr}}' file
```

Here's what I want the output to be.

```
151 chr1    8346    8346    345y46htyh
151 chr1    8346    8346    76jtuj
```

And here's what the output is.

```
151 chr1    8346    8346    76jtuj
151 chr1    8346    8346    76jtuj
```

Comment: I made a mistake while entering that line; I amended it.

Comment: What should the output be if a line like `153 chr1    8045    8045    foo` appeared at the end of your posted sample input? Should the earlier `139 chr1    8045    8045    34e5rg  4r` be printed and then that new line since both have common $2/$3/$4 values? If so where should it appear - before the 151 lines or after them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2$3$4]++;next} a[($2$3$4)]>1' Input_file Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk '{k=$2 FS $3 FS $4} FNR==NR{a[k]++;next} a[k]>1'  Input_file Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
151 chr1    8346    8346    345y46htyh
151 chr1    8346    8346    76jtuj
```

Comment: @DangIt, could you please try this one once and  let me know if this helps you?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but for me the output is an empty file.

Comment: @DangIt, could you please do let me know if you have  mentioned Input_file 2 times? I am reading file 2 times.

Comment: You're right; I forgot to put it in a second time. Why is it that I need to enter the input file twice? As in, would there be any advantages in being able to call two different input files?

Comment: It checks which keys exist multiple times in the file, and then on the second pass prints those. The teo rounds are an inefficiency but lets you handle files where the duplicates may not be adjacent.

Comment: @DangIt, IMHO since first time file reading I am only creating array and next checking condition, I don't think so it should delay things. Rest you could let me know here your experience too.

Answer (score 1):

You *are* printing the same line twice. It's not entirely clear what you want the logic to be, but surely one of the `print` statements should be `print curr` or perhaps `print prev`. <del>Also the lone `prev` doesn't do anything, and looks like it was left over from an editing mistake.</del>

Perhaps you are looking for something like

```
awk '++array[$2$3$4] >= 2 {
        if(prev)print prev;
        print;
        prev = ""; next }
    { prev = $0 }' file
```

If that doesn't do what you want, maybe edit your question to describe in more detail what you hope your current script should do; code which doesn't do what you want isn't really a good way to communicate what you do want.

Comment: What is the purpose of `prev = ""`? To me, it looks like `{prev = $0}` will overwrite that anyway.

Comment: It's to avoid printing `prev` more than once if there is a third or fourth repeat. The `next` bypasses the block which contains the `prev = $0` assignment.

Comment: `a bc` -> `abc`. `ab c` -> `abc`. When creating unique keys by concatenating fields you need to include separators: `{k=$2 FS $3 FS $4}`.

Comment: That's a good fix if the fields might actually be ambiguous. The sample data looks like the second field would not have a lot of variation.

Comment: I'm not convinced that `chrN` will always ends in 1 digit vs 2, nor that the numeric columns are always 4 digits vs 3 or 5 or something else but maybe I'm just being paranoid, idk.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another awk solution that doesn't read input file twice and works even if your input is not sorted.

```
awk '(k = $2 FS $3 FS $4) in a {
  print a[k] $0; a[k] = ""; next
} { a[k] = $0 ORS }' file
```

Comment: Using the full data set, it works correctly for the first duplicate pair, but it only outputs  the second duplicate of each duplicate pair after that.

Comment: @DangIt that's hard to believe unless $2/3/4 keys can recur in later lines. You should include that use case in your posted sample input/output so people can test potential solutions against it.